# Is there a way to locate a data frame between a set of date ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, mask, pandas-loc

I have seen many ways to locate a data frame for one date range,

i.e.

```
mask = (df["TimeStamp"] > date_range[0]) & (df["TimeStamp"] < date_range[1])
df = df.loc[mask]
```

but I can't find out how to do this if I had multiple date ranges

i.e.

```
date_ranges = [date_range_1, date_range_2, date_range_3, ... , date_range_n]
```

I would need something like

```
mask = ()

for date_range in date_ranges:
    sub_mask = (df["TimeStamp"] > date_range[0]) & (df["TimeStamp"] < date_range[1])
    mask.append(sub_mask)

df = df.loc[mask]
```

but of course this doesn't work for a variety of reasons (you need an or statement between the ands, and you cant append these masks in this way)

could anybody give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could change your code using :

```py
mask = 0
for date_range in date_ranges:
    sub_mask = (df["TimeStamp"] > date_range[0]) & (df["TimeStamp"] < date_range[1])
    mask = (mask | sub_mask)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mask = (1 | mask) will always return 1 on last bit

```py
mask = 0
```

Comment: yeah you're right sorry, but you should put it as a comment and not as an actual answer